# Variables in PostgreSQL loops

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables, loops, plpgsql

I have the following function (returns a set of custom types)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction(in_myvar integer)
  RETURNS SETOF my_type AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
    v_data my_type%rowtype;
    v_another_var text;
BEGIN
    FOR v_data IN (

        -- I want to be able to do a SELECT INTO v_another_var in each iteration
        -- of the loop, ideally so I can use this value throughout the select
        -- statement e.g.:
        -- SELECT INTO v_another_var regex_replace(col3, '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '');

        SELECT DISTINCT 
            col1
            col2,
            -- v_another_var AS some_column
            -- etc.
            -- perhaps use this v_another_var again here
            -- as part of something else.
          FROM mytable
          WHERE v_another_var = 'test' + some_function() = 'something'
                    -- want to use the variable again here.
    ) LOOP
        RETURN NEXT v_data;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
$BODY$
```

Is it possible to assign a variable and use it in each select statement as part of a loop in this way? Even if this is possible, would the SELECT INTO statement work where I have it (would col3 be accessible?)

Is there a way in postgres to achieve this kind of variable usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to SELECT the value for v_another_var in the query controlling you loop, or inside the `LOOP`/`END LOOP` construct, if you want a different value in each iteration of the loop.  You can always have additional queries to assign other values inside the loop if needed.

It's hard to make a more concrete suggestion without a more concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a mess. Much of it does not make any sense at all.

> Is it possible to assign a variable and use it in each select
>   statement as part of a loop in this way?

- You only have *one* SELECT statement in your question. You are not making sense.
- There is no loop "in" a SELECT statement. You can loop through the rows resulting from a SELECT statement.

> Even if this is possible, would the INSERT INTO statement work where I
>   have it (would col3 be accessible?)

- It would not at all. Neither where you have it nor what you have there.

  - Maybe you meant SELECT INTO?
  - There is no `FROM` clause, `col3` is undefined.
  - Only *one* statement in the FOR loop. More about that further down.

Furthermore ...

- No parenthesis required for the SELECT of a FOR loop.
- [`regexp_replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), not `regex_replace()`.
- Text concatenation in PostgreSQL: `'test' || some_function()`
  not `'test' + some_function()`
- You need parentheses around `WHERE x = (a || b)`
- Language declaration is missing. Add `language plpgsql` at the end.

---

What you **may be asking** (wild guess):
Yes, you can assign multiple variables in a `FOR` loop. [I quote the manual here:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING)

> The target is a record variable, row variable, or comma-separated list
>   of scalar variables.

You cannot mix a record variable and a scalar variable, though, as you seem to be trying. You would have to ...

a) split up the composite type `v_data` into scalar variables and list them in order, then append `v_another_var` to the FOR target list.

or b) add a text column (instead of `v_another_var`) to the composite type `my_type`. However, you would have to reorganize the `RETURN NEXT` statement in this case. Since I am just guessing what your question might be, I will not go into more details.

Clean up your question and ask a precise question if you want a precise answer.

Comment: Wow sorry. I've not deliberately tried to make this question complicated/messy - I guess I don't really understand how this works all that well.